# In SwiftUI, how to draw shadows with high performance?

Tags: swift, swiftui, shadow

I use the `.shadow(color:, radius:, x:, y:)` to draw shadows in my application. This is the only way I know of drawing apps in SwiftUI. I use the `.sheet(isPresented:, content:)` method to pop up a view, which contains a lot of shadows, and when I debug view hierarchy, I saw these warnings:

[image]

But I don't know how to setting `shadowPath`, or pre-rendering the shadow into an image and putting it under the layer in SwiftUI, please help me.

Comment: Would you show your code or example of how to reproduce this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This warning is not caused because your code is inherently bad, but as a way of telling you that there are much more performant ways of rendering shadows.

As your UI elements are currently written, SwiftUI is drawing the shadows around your view objects dynamically (at Runtime) based on wherever their positions and bounds are at the time, and that rendering will follow the view throughout it's lifecycle.

It's a math intensive process and involves many draw-calls to the GPU in the best of cases, and CPU bottlenecking as well in the worst of cases.

There are several different ways of rendering shadows in Swift.  Most of them utilize frameworks OUTSIDE of SwiftUI (UIKit and CoreGraphics, usually, though Metal, Core Animation, and Core Image have been important in various applications.)

This warning is probably not a big deal if you're not seeing performance problems in the UI layer on target hardware, but if you're very motivated to solve the problem, there are some options:

---

### Option 1

The absolute easiest thing to do if you just want to make the error go away would be to force a GPU call rasterization for the view + shadow by adding

```
.drawingGroup()
```

somewhere after the .shadow view.  Be advised, this will likely look like crap compared to dynamic shadows.  If you're familiar with UIKit, this is similar to the layer.shouldRasterize property on UIView.

---

### Option 2

Speaking of UIKit, an alternative would be to head over there and use either a UIViewRepresentable of your SwiftUI drawing logic, or a completely separate UIView.  Either way:

```
myView = UIView()
myView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: myView.bounds.cgPath)
```

should get you started... the other shadow properties and stuff will help.

---

### Option 3

You could render the shadow as an image, either programatically (hard) or in an imaging editing application (annoying) and load is as an image at a lower Z index than your view, and scale them to give the illusion of depth.

This is the kind of hacky work around that game developers used to do when they had crappy hardware but still wanted things to look good.

---

In the end... for MOST SwiftUI views this warning likely can be ignored.  If you load the code in Instruments, you'll likely see that the dynamic rendering of drop shadows under a View is probably not impacting your view rendering performance significantly.  This warning is only usually visible inside a UI Debug session.

Hope this helps set you on the path to a solution.

Comment: Using .drawingGroup() launches RAM usage to the moon! At least on views from a List with lots of images. Not sure why though. Seems that the rasterized views are being kept in memory.

Comment: Yes, .drawingGroup(), just like layer.shouldRasterize, would put all your views into RAM for rapid access later.  That's kinda the definition of rasterization... it has much slower initial setup time, because it has to load the image in RAM... but then it can animate and move the item faster, because it doesn't have to re-compute the drawing for every frame, it just grabs it in memory.  Everything is a trade off... lazy/easy to implement vs performant results vs adaptability vs binary size.  Make good choices.  ;)

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this this week. And I think I figured out a way that is as performant as the shadowPath option in UIKit. I *think* that when you use `Shape().shadow(...)` it draws an efficient shadow based on the path. So IF you know the shape of the thing you're giving a shadow to, you can do it like this:

```swift
content
  // Use background so the shadow is the same size as the content
  .background(
    // I'm assuming rectangle but it can be anything like with rounded corners too
    Rectangle()
      // Add efficient shadow
      .shadow()
      // Add an inset so you don't see the ugly inner edge of the shadow, it will be under your content
      .padding(1)
  )
```

This was much much faster than what I had before!

Comment: Note `.drawingGroup` didn't work well for me because it clipped my shadow too much.

Comment: Definitely improved over shadowing a home-brewed view.

Comment: Can confirm that this does remove the offscreen pass. I was surprised that setting `contentShape` seemed to do nothing in this regard as it would seem to be a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that it is very costly to add shadow after an overlay to a shape. As I assume adding a shadow afterwards would make SwiftUI recalculate the path of the new shadow, regardless how small the change is. So it is best to draw shadow before overlay.