# SwiftUI: Adding a Shadow to View in List/Grid is Lagging UI

Tags: swiftui

When adding a shadow to my view in a Grid, the scrolling experience is bad. It feels like the Frame Rate is dropping. I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077689/in-swiftui-how-to-draw-shadows-with-high-performance), option 1 made my whole background for my view the same color as my shadow. I Don't really know how to implement UIViewRepresentable in option 2.

So how would I be able to use UIViewRepresentable, or is there a better way to do this.

**MRE CODE**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var gridSpacing: CGFloat = 8
    let columns: [GridItem] = [GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 8), GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 8),GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 8)]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: gridSpacing) {
                ForEach(0..<200) { x in
                    VStack(spacing: 8) {
                        Image("sumo-deadlift") //<----- Replace Image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .background(.yellow)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .shadow(color: .blue, radius: 2, x: 1, y: 1) //<----- Comment/Uncomment
                        
                        Text("Sumo Deadlift")
                            .font(.footnote.weight(.semibold))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .lineLimit(2)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        
                        Text("Legs")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    }
                    .padding(.all)
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous))
                    .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                    .shadow(color: .red, radius: 2, x: 1, y: 1) //<----- Comment/Uncomment
                }
            }
            .padding(.all, 8)
        }
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I replaced the image with an SF Symbol, and the interface is buttery smooth. I would be looking at the image you are using. Can that be optimized?