# Does SwiftUI perform any additional computation if .shadow radius is set to 0?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, swiftui

I'm working on optimizing few components and am introduction an optional shadow option i.e.

```
VStack {
 ...
}
.shadow(radius: isShadow ? 0 : 10)
```

The idea here is to not render shadows where they are not needed and save a bit of compute time, but I'm not sure if this use case actually achieves it.

Would appreciate a detailed explanation, maybe with references on whether performance would be a bit better with shadow of radius 0 or not. And why.

Comment: Why do you care? If you want an optional shadow, how else would you do it? Note that If you use an `if isShadow { ... } else { ... }` instead, you would also change the semantics.

Comment: You may also try to set the color to `clear` instead using a radius of `0`. With radius 0, a shadow _might_ still be drawn "with sharp edges" - albeit with no visible differences, if the x and y is zero as well. Both methods _should_ be optimised early in SwiftUI before going to the renderer.

Comment: @Sweeper trying to understand if approach like this would work in a sense where there are 20 elements with shadow on a page or say only 5, with all others having shadow of 0. While minuscule, there must be a performance hit in case where all 20 of them have the shadow, correct?

Comment: Yes, probably. How is this information useful? I don't see anything actionable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74659992/22907942

It states that you should be able to optimise your shadow drawing performance by using `Shape().shadow(...)` in the background layer.